# Host timezone not reflect on spring-boot docker container

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, timezone, localtime

I'm trying to set a localtime to my docker container as the same as my localtime locally to use on a spring-boot application when save a data.

spring-boot app:

```
...
cpoWorkflowExecution.setStartDate(LocalDateTime.now());
...
```

Local localtime:

```
[ainacio@brsp1nf01 cpo-dockers]$ ls -l /etc/localtime
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 39 Oct  6 07:42 /etc/localtime -> ../usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Sao_Paulo
```

Local timezone:

```
[ainacio@brsp1nf01 cpo-dockers]$ cat /etc/timezone 
America/Sao_Paulo
```

**Container localtime didn't work**:

```
root@ffbd68eeaccd:/# ls -l /etc/localtime
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 27 Nov 17 13:37 /etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC
```

Container timezone worked:

```
root@ffbd68eeaccd:/# cat /etc/timezone 
America/Sao_Paulo
```

Docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
    cpo-executor:
        container_name: cpo-executor
        image: .../cpo-executor:1.103.3.1
        ports:
          - 8879:8879
        environment:
          - TZ=America/Sao_Paulo
        volumes:
          - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
          - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
        networks:
          - cpo-network
        depends_on:
          - cpo-config-server
```

I've also tried to set **TZ** environment variable but it didn't work as well.

I'm generating the docker image using spring-boot maven plugin:

```
mvn spring-boot:build-image -DskipTests -Dspring-boot.build-image.imageName=.../cpo-executor:1.103.3.1
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Same issue here! Did you find out what the problem is?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet :(.